# Show that if $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, proof-verification, stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

> Show that, if $\{X_n\}$ is a Markov Chain then
>   $$P(X_n=j\mid X_k=l,X_m=i)=P(X_n=j\mid X_m=i),0\leq k<m<n$$

What I did is

$$P(X_n=j\mid X_k=l,X_m=i)=\frac{P(X_n=j,X_k=l,X_m=i)}{P(X_k=l,X_m=i)}=\frac{\sum_{i_{n-1},\dots,i_0}P(X_n=j,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},\dots,X_{m+1}=i_{m+1},X_m=i,\dots,X_k=l,\dots,X_0=i_0)}{P(X_k=l,X_m=i)}$$

$$=\frac{\sum_{i_{n-1},\dots,i_0}P(X_n=j,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1}, \dots,X_{m+1}=i_{m+1}\mid X_m=i,\dots,X_k=l,\dots,X_0=i_0)P(X_m=i,\dots,X_k=l,\dots,X_0=i_0)}{P(X_k=l,X_m=i)}$$

$$=P(X_n=j\mid X_m=i)*\frac{\sum_{i_{n-1}, \dots,i_0}P(X_m=i,\dots,X_k=l,\dots,X_0=i_0)}{P(X_k=l,X_m=i)}=P(X_n=j\mid X_m=i)$$

Is it right? Is there an easier way?

Comment: I changed {$X_n$} to $\{X_n\}$.  The latter is standard and with the former you get mismatches in font and size, and lack of proper spacing.  Also, I added proper use of \mid. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's it.

A Markov chain is a sequence of random variables $\{X_k\}_{k\in\{0..n\}}$ representing $n+1$ subsequent states of a system, such that for all supported values $\{i_k\}_{k\in\{0..b\}}$, and $i_c$, where $0\leq a< b< c\leq n$ we have:

$$\mathsf P(X_c=i_c\mid \bigcap_{k\in\{0..b\}} X_k=i_k)= \mathsf P(X_c=i_c\mid X_b=i_b)$$

So if we let: $K =\{0..a-1\}\cup\{a+1..b-1\}$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
& \mathsf P(X_c=i_c\mid X_b=i_b, X_a=i_a) 
\\[2ex] = & \sum_{\{i_k\}_{k\in K}} {\mathsf P(X_c=i_c\mid X_b=i_b, X_a=i_a,\bigcap_{k\in K}X_k=i_k)\;\mathsf P(\bigcap_{k\in K}X_k=i_k)} 
\\[2ex] = & \mathsf P(X_c=i_c\mid X_b=i_b)\sum_{\{i_k\}_{k\in K}} \mathsf P(\bigcap_{k\in K}X_k=i_k)
\\[2ex] = & \mathsf P(X_c=i_c\mid X_b=i_b)
\end{align}
$$

Which is what you said; but perhaps a little more compactly.